# symfony2 controller works fine in view, but does not during load:fixtures

Tags: symfony, controller, doctrine, entity, fixtures

I am struggling with the combination of a Controller, an EntityRepository, and my Doctrine Fixtures in Symfony2.

My ImageParts Entity are pieces of images. I want to randomly generate images, using random pieces.

So, I have an entity called ImagePart, and an EntityRepository with the name 'ImagePartRepository'.

Within that EntityRepository, I created a function called 'getRandomImagePart()', which is working fine when testing it using a route.

But I cannot figure out how I can use this function within my fixtures. I THINK I have to declare a service, but even then I cannot get it to work. The type of error messages I get tells me that I'm clearly doing something structurally wrong.

Furthermore, I am wondering if I use the Symfony2 framework the correct way, functional. Eg: Should I be able to use an EntityRepository within my fixtures.

Controller:

```
    <?php

    namespace AMM\AMMBundle\Controller;

    use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
    use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
    use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;

    use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
    use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareInterface;
    use Symfony\Component\Finder\Finder;

    use AMM\AMMBundle\Entity\ImagePart;
    use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;


    class ImagePartController extends Controller implements ContainerAwareInterface
    {
        /**
         * @var ContainerInterface
         */
        protected $container;

        /**
         * {@inheritDoc}
         */
        public function setContainer(ContainerInterface $container = null)
        {
            $this->container = $container;
        }


        public function getRandomImagePartAction($type)
        {
            /*
            $sql = " 
                SELECT a.imagePartBase64 FROM imageparts a
                WHERE a.imagePartCategory = '".$type."'
                ORDER BY RAND()
                LIMIT 1
            ";
            */

            $em = $this->getDoctrine()
                       ->getManager();

            $imagePart = $em->createQueryBuilder()
                        ->select('g')
                        ->from('AMMBundle:ImagePart',  'i')
                        ->addOrderBy('i.id', 'ASC')
                        ->getQuery()
                        ->getSingleResult();

          // $conn = $this->get('database_connection');
            //$randomimagepart = $conn->fetchAll($sql);


           // return $randomimagepart[0]['imagePartBase64'];

            return $imagePart;
        }

// ..

public function generateRandomImage()
    {
      $object->getRandomImagePartAction('BACKGROUND');
    }
```

Fixture file ImageFixtures.php

```
<?php
namespace AMM\AMMBundle\DataFixtures\ORM;

use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\FixtureInterface;
use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\OrderedFixtureInterface;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

use AMM\AMMBundle\Entity\ImagePart;

class GenerateImages implements FixtureInterface, ContainerAwareInterface, OrderedFixtureInterface
{
    private $container;

    public function load(Objectmanager $manager)
    {
        $image= new Image();

        $imageGenerator = $this->container
                               ->get('imageGenerator')
                                ->GenerateRandomImage();

        $manager->persist($image);      
        $manager->flush();

}
```

My services.yml:

```
services:
    imageGenerator:
        class:        AMM\AMMBundle\Controller\ImagePartController
```

So, basically what I do is call a function from a function in the same controller. This works fine when testing it, for example, in a view.

But when trying to load doctrine fixtures, the following error occurs:

Fatal error: Call to a member function has() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\amm\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller.php on line 198

The end of the stack trace:

```
5.7077   41983128  15. AMM\AMMBundle\Controller\ImagePartController->getRandomImagePartAction() C:\wamp\www\amm\src\AMM\AMMBundle\Controller\ImagePartController.php:119
5.7077   41983128  16. Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller->getDoctrine() C:\wamp\www\amm\src\AMM\AMMBundle\Controller\ImagePartController.php:44
```

Comment: How can we fix something that is not defined? Try posting some code snippets we can handle it.

Comment: Hi David, I just posted some snippets. Basically I want to call a function from a function within the same controller. Works fine from a view, but doesn't during fixtures:load.

Comment: Ok, I found the problem. I had to add this to my services.yml:

        calls:
          - [setContainer, [@service_container]]

Comment: Please answer your questing in a answer comment so other people can see if it's answered and Google can see it too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the problem.

I had to add this to my services.yml:

```
calls: - [setContainer, [@service_container]] –
```